# Making a variable accessible in two different types of <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable in a  and want this variable to also be read in a  later on in the program. Does anyone know how I can do this? My code is here but doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var temp0;
// set temp0
</script>

<script>
// I want to be able to read the value of temp0 here
</script>
```

Comment: And did you try it, should work fine !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3DHdf/

Comment: This is what I have at the moment but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am reading it wrong in the <script> part.

Comment: @benandrews54 post the actual code you are using, without your code there's no way to know why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Turns out I needed to convert the var to a number for it to work properly with highcharts. I thought my issue was that the variable was not passing correctly, turns out I was wrong! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking what you want to do is doable in JavaScript.  It's tough to say why it isn't working for you without that you post the actual code that doesn't work.

It could be a scope issue, see the following articles for a write-up on JavaScript variable scopes:

[JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting Explained](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)

[Explaining JavaScript scope and closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

[Variable Scope (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) @ MSDN